# OpenCV ImportError using python

Tags: opencv, python-3.5

I'm trying to work with OpenCV3 in Python 3.5. I installed it but when I call

```
import cv2
```

I get this error message:

> ImportError: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmirprotobuf.so.3: undefined
>   symbol:
>   _ZNK6google8protobuf11MessageLite25InitializationErrorStringB5cxx11Ev

Anybody ever had this error? Thanks.

Comment: Did you get any errors during the installation? Please edit the question to include your operating system, and the steps used to install.